# Install new heroku-toolbelt in raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian-wheezy

I had the heroku-toolbelt installed on my raspberry pi. With the new v4 release of the heroku-toolbelt it started to fail and I had to reinstall it:

```
wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

Now when checking the installation it looks heroku is under the right path:

```
$ which heroku
/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku
```

But when running any heroku commands it tries to update itself and fails:

```
$ heroku --version
Installing Heroku Toolbelt v4... done.
For more information on Toolbelt v4: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli
Illegal instruction
Illegal instruction
 !    error getting commands pid 3275 exit 132
```

If I try to install it with the standalone way it is just the same:

```
wget -O- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh

 $ heroku login
Installing Heroku Toolbelt v4... done.
For more information on Toolbelt v4: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli
Illegal instruction
Illegal instruction
 !    error getting commands pid 3531 exit 132
```

Of course I uninstalled it first (both versions, ubuntu one and standalone) before trying to install it again but I had the same result. 
I also updated and upgraded my raspbian as well (sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade).

Why am I getting this error and how can I solve it?

Note: I am under Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)

Comment: Seems interesting. Never thought of Heroku on a Raspberry Pi, I've just used it on my Mac. I'll answer your question now.

Answer (score 0):

You probably still have the old Heroku installed. Can you try this:

`sudo apt-get remove heroku-toolbelt
 sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list`

Once you've done that, reinstall and try again. Or you could use use this as an opportunity to upgrade to Jessie, and wipe your card and install it on Jessie.

Comment: I tried that before writing here. I actually followed the official docs: [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command#uninstalling-the-heroku-cli)

Comment: Ah ha. Did you try it on a new install? Maybe with Jessie?

Comment: No, I haven't. I got some other projects in my pi and I just can't upgrade without checking quite a few things. And as I said it used to work ok.

Comment: All right. Do you have a fresh SD Card around?

Comment: I see your point but I would like to find a less disruptive solution.

Comment: @gugol That is very reasonable. It was merely a suggestion. Could you try just `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: Have you tried to install it in a raspberry pi? Was it a successful installation? Under what OS and version did you try? That would help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the standalone installation, as of 9/30/17, arm is now available:

wget https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-cli/channels/stable/heroku-cli-linux-arm.tar.gz -O heroku.tar.gz

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#standalone